# dijkstra's algorithm - from A to B

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I know what dijkstra's algorithm is. And I know it is optimal when used for finding all the paths from A to all other possible nodes. However is it optimal if you are trying to find the path from A to B? In other words, should it be used when searching a path from A to B or are there other better algorithms for this use case.

EDIT: If I break the loop exactly after I have found my destination node I think that it won't work. Let's say I have this graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/orp0N.png and I am trying to go from A to D. Since this algorithm is greedy it will first go A->B, B->F(dead end), B->E, E->D and the total weight will be 9. Although there is a shorter path. Which will be found eventually after this path.

Comment: Possible alternatives (apart from stopping when you reached your target like mangusta suggests) are bidirectional Dijkstra (start at A and B simultaneously) or A*. The latter assumes that you have a reasonable heuristic about the distance of a path between two points. If you don't, it will degenerate to Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find the distance to ALL nodes from A. You simply quit the loop after you put B into shortest-path tree.
There is no better algorithm from the point of view of performance. All algorithms finding shortest path from a specific node run with O(n^2) in the worst case.

EDIT. However a slightly better performance could be achieved if we take into account some specific features of a processed graph (e.g. the ratio of the number of vertices and edges)

EDIT2.  Regarding your sample graph. Here are the steps:
1. A is added to shortest-path tree (SPT)
2. Update its neighbors not in SPT. dist(B)=3
3. Pick vertex with min.dist. not in SPT. that's B. add B to SPT.
4. Update its neighbors not in SPT. dist(C)=6, dist(E)=5, dist(F)=4
5. Pick vertex with min.dist. not in SPT. that's F. add F to SPT.
6. F has no neighbors.
7. Pick vertex with min.dist. not in SPT. that's E. add E to SPT.
8. Update its neighbors not in SPT. dist(D)=9
9. Pick vertex with min.dist. not in SPT. that's C. add C to SPT.
10. Update its neighbors not in SPT. dist(D)=7.
11. Pick vertex with min.dist. not in SPT. that's D. add D to SPT.
Done

Comment: O(n^2)? Where do you have that from? Dijkstra is a perfect counter-example, which runs in O(E + V log V).

Comment: @Nico Schertler well, you're partly right, I was talking about the canonical version of Dijkstra. The complexity you mentioned is the one for an enhanced version of Dijkstra which takes advantage of sparse graphs.

Comment: @mangusta If I quit right after I meet B, I don't think that the algorithm will work

Comment: @john you're confusing "meeting" with "putting into a shortest-path tree", those are two different things. You need to quit after putting B into shortest-path tree, not after simply meeting it

Comment: @mangusta I thought that dijkstra's algorithm doesn't have anything related to shortest-path tree, at least from the wikipedia article

Comment: @NicoSchertler: E is at most (V²-V)/2, so as a function of V, E + V log V is worst-case Θ(V²).

Comment: @john actually the very purpose of Dijkstra's algorithm is the construction of a shortest-path tree of a given graph : ) possibly you confuse it with minimum spanning tree

Comment: @ruakh so as a whole, is dijkstra's algorithm efficient for finding from point A to B? plain dijkstra's, no modifications

Comment: @john if you mean finding all distances from A, of course it is inefficient : ) why do you need spending time on other vertices

Comment: @mangusta still confused though... please recheck my question

Comment: @mangusta I just don't get why we add every node in the SPT? I mean I thought I should add only the necessary ones(the shortest path)

Comment: @john adding the node into SPT implies that all possible paths leading to that node from start node A have been investigated. in order to find shortest path to B we need to be sure about shortest paths from A to all intermediate nodes staying on the paths between A and B, that's the invariant for Dijkstra's algorithm